# Get found items as list from regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, list

Given the following code:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "red", "blue", "green" };
Regex r = new Regex("\\b(" + string.Join("|", myList.ToArray()) + ")\\b");
MatchCollection m = r.Matches("Alfred has a red and blue tie and blue pants.");
```

Is there a way to derive a `List<string>` of the "found" items ("red", "blue", "blue")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var n = (from Match match in m
         select match.Value).ToList()
```

Comment: Wow.  I was using foreach (var match in m).  When I changed it to foreach (Match match in m), it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Since m does not impelement IEnumerable<T> you need to specifically tell the compiler that you are dealing with Match objects. Presumably your var was an object